# Find a plane that is parallel with $z$-axis and the line $r = (\lambda+ 1, \lambda - 1, 1 -\lambda)$, passes through $A(-2, 3, 0)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

As the title says, I have to find a plane parallel to the z-axis and the line $r = (\lambda + 1, \lambda - 1, 1 - \lambda)$. The plane also passes through the point $A(-2, 3, 0)$.

Now, I was thinking, since the plane is parallel to the $z$-axis, then the normal vector of the plane would be perpendicular to the $z$-axis. Am I wrong here?

Could someone solve this task step-by-step, explaining the reasoning as best as possible? I can't seem to figure it out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! 

Have a look at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). 

Here is a very cool little tool called [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) where you can 
draw the symbol you are looking for and the system will tell you what the TeX command is.

Finally, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
as a quick reference for future posts.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: HINT: How can you find a vector perpendicular to 2 given vectors? If you can do that find the 2 given vectors in the problem and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write the line in vector form:
$$
r(\lambda) = (\lambda+ 1, \lambda - 1, 1 -\lambda)
=(1,-1,1)+\lambda(1,1,-1)
$$
Hence, your plane is parallel to the direction vector of the line $r$, namely to the vector $(1,1,-1)$. In order to determine the plane completely, you need another direction vector. Since the plane parallel to $z$-axis, it follows that another direction vector is $(1,0,0)$. Since your plane pass trough the point $A(-2,3,0)$, it follows that , the parametric equation of the plane is 
$$
\pi(t,s)=(-2,3,0)+t(1,1,-1)+s(0,0,1)
$$
To find the plane equation, set
$$
(x,y,z)=(-2,3,0)+t(1,1,-1)+s(0,0,1).
$$
Thus 
$$
\begin{cases}
x=-2+t\\
y=3+t\\
z=s
\end{cases}
$$
so the plane equation is 
$$
x-y=-5
$$

Comment: Thank you for responding. I do have one question though: How did you get from the parametric equation (where $x = -2 + t$, $y = 3 + t$ and $z = s$) to $x - y = -5$? I tried expressing $t$ and $s$, but the problem is I don't use both $t$ and $s$ in one of my coordinates.

Comment: You don't need to express t and s, only to obtain an equation of the form $Ax+By+CZ=D$ without t and s. In this case $1x+(-1)y+0z=-5$. Note that $x+2=t$ and $y-3=t$, so $x+2=y-3$, that is $x-y=-5$

Comment: And what did you do with the s?

Comment: s is a free variable, as z is.